# Automatically disable Linux extensions for Samba mounts

Tags: osx, samba, cifs

Samba enables Linux Extensions by default, which can be checked via /proc/fs/cifs/LinuxExtensionsEnabled

On Mac OS X (10.8.5 or older) as well as older CIFS shares, mount.cifs will fail with a generic error message:

```
 CIFS VFS: Send error in QFSUnixInfo = -95
 CIFS VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed
```

The workaround is to manually disable Linux extensions

```
$ sudo echo 0 > /proc/fs/cifs/LinuxExtensionsEnabled
```

Is there an option that I can pass along to disable Linux extensions, such as

```
$ mount -t cifs -o linuxextensions=n .....
```

Or can I disable it on boot automatically?

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the [Samba manual](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html)

> nounix Disable the CIFS Unix Extensions for this mount. This can be
>   useful in order to turn off multiple settings at once. This includes
>   POSIX acls, POSIX locks, POSIX paths, symlink support and retrieving
>   uids/gids/mode from the server. This can also be useful to work around
>   a bug in a server that supports Unix Extensions.
>
> See section INODE NUMBERS for more information.

The terms "Linuxextensions" and "nounix" does not seem to refer to the same thing, but they actually do.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use automounts to automatically mount & unmounts the CIFS shares. This would allow them to be mounted when used and then unmounted after a period of inactivity.

This is a RedHat guide but should be adaptable to MacOSX, titled: [18.3. autofs](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-nfs-client-config-autofs.html).

#### Example

After installing `autofs` you'll need to add an entry to the file `/etc/auto.master`:

```
/somemount          /etc/auto.mymounts --timeout=600 --ghost
```

Then add an entry to the mymounts file, `/etc/auto.mymounts`:

```
t                  -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,netbiosname=${HOST},credentials=/etc/cifsserver_credentials.txt ://cifsserver/t
```

Lastly you'll need to add an entry in the credentials file, `/etc/cifsserver_credentials.txt`:

```
username=someuser
password=somepass
```

Now start up `autofs`. This is going to create a mountpoint `/somemount` with a mount under it, `t`. The mount `t` will get mounted automatically anytime someone accesses it. After 5 minutes of inactivity the mount will be dropped. Accessing it again will remount it.

This is a highlevel guide, there are bound to be details I've left out, but just to give you a rough idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out to be the `nounix` option. :)

Comment: @hanxue - not a problem, I was showing you a more long term solution for dealing with the mounting of CIFS shares. `autofs` can also mount other things, it isn't just for CIFS. Glad you solved your issue.