# Preserving owner/group on OS X-provided CIFS shares

Tags: ubuntu, osx, cifs

I read the attached StackExchange link: [Automatically disable Linux extensions for Samba mounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96290/automatically-disable-linux-extensions-for-samba-mounts) about disabling CIFS Unix Extensions in order to mount OS X CIFS shares.  However, my understanding is that this also disables the server from being able to set the owner/group of the files.

Is this correct?  Is there a way to override this, or preserve owner/group information?

Update:  I thought, perhaps, the multiuser option would help.  Apparently OS X doesn't allow that either unless someone else has gotten that to work?